# How to bind to a property of a UserControl in WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I'm trying to bind to a property of a user control, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<Controls:BasicFilter Title="Some title" FilterLists="{Binding LocationFilterLists}"/>
```

`FilterLists` is the property I'm trying to bind to. Title property contains a text which is shown on a label within my control and this works well.

I've set up a basic ViewModel which tries to set `LocationFilterLists`. Because it's bound to `FilterLists` property of my control, I was hoping this would set that value to that property, but that doesn't happen. Here's the code of my ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : DependencyObject
{
 public NamedListList LocationFilterLists
 {
  get { return (NamedListList)GetValue(LocationFilterListsProperty); }
  set { SetValue(LocationFilterListsProperty, value); }
 }
 public static readonly DependencyProperty LocationFilterListsProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("LocationFilterLists", typeof(NamedListList), typeof(MainViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));

 public MainViewModel()
 {
 }

 internal void Refresh()
 {
  NamedListList nll = new NamedListList();
  NamedList nl1 = new NamedList();
  nl1.Name = "filter1";
  NamedList nl2 = new NamedList();
  nl2.Name = "filter2";
  nll.Add(nl1);
  nll.Add(nl2);
  LocationFilterLists = nll;
 }
}
```

`NamedList` inherits from `List<object>` and adds a property `Name`, and `NamedListList` inherits from `List<NamedList>`. I've set up the view to call the `Refresh` method as soon as DataContext is set to this ViewModel.

Here's my control's XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Plin.CommonDisplayObjects.Controls.BasicFilter"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d">
 <Grid Background="Gray">
  <DockPanel x:Name="dockPanel" Margin="3">
   <Label Content="{Binding Title}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0" Padding="5,3,5,3"/>
  </DockPanel>
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here's the code-behind of my control:

```
public partial class BasicFilter : UserControl
{
 #region Dependency Properties
 public string Title
 {
  get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
  set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
 }
 public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(BasicFilter), new PropertyMetadata(""));

 public NamedListList FilterLists
 {
  get { return (NamedListList)GetValue(FilterListsProperty); }
  set
  {
   SetValue(FilterListsProperty, value);
   RegenerateFilter(); // Every time property is set, new buttons should be generated.
  }
 }
 public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterListsProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("FilterLists", typeof(NamedListList), typeof(BasicFilter), new PropertyMetadata(null));
 #endregion

 public BasicFilter()
 {
  InitializeComponent();
  this.DataContext = this;
 }

 private void RegenerateFilter()
 {
  dockPanel.Children.Clear();
  if (FilterLists != null)
  {
   foreach (NamedList nl in FilterLists)
   {
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Content = "Some generic content " + nl.Name;
    // set other properties on Button
    dockPanel.Children.Add(b);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

On startup, two buttons should appear on my control, but none appears in this case. I've tried setting `FilterLists` property programmatically (by passing a view reference to ViewModel, naming my control and `viewReference.myControl.FilterLists = nll;`) and this works, but I'd prefer to be able to bind as shown above. What am I missing?

Comment: `this.DataContext = this;` Don't do this.  Please.  In your UserControls, simply use Binding.ElementName to reference the UserControl (give the root of the control an x:Name, and use this when binding controls to properties on the surface of the UserControl.  You're setting yourself up for heartbreak with this practice.

Comment: @Will, yes, I've changed this, we've covered it in Clemens' answer (see comments there).

Comment: Also, before you're tempted, don't create ViewModels for your UserControls.  UCs should be UI only, and any logic/bindings they need should exist in the codebehind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to do anything except then `SetValue` in the CLR wrapper of a dependency property, as the wrapper may be bypassed by WPF. See the [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563.aspx) article on MSDN for details.

Instead of calling `RegenerateFilter()` in the setter, you'll have to register a PropertyChangedCallback with dependency property metadata:

```
public NamedListList FilterLists
{
    get { return (NamedListList)GetValue(FilterListsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FilterListsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FilterListsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "FilterLists", typeof(NamedListList), typeof(BasicFilter),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, FilterListsPropertyChanged));

private static void FilterListsPropertyChanged(
    DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((BasicFilter)o).RegenerateFilter();
}
```

---

That said, your view model should not be derived from DependencyObject and declare dependency properties. Instead, it should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, and use ObservableCollections if collection changes have to be notified.

---

Edit: Due to the statement `this.DataContext = this;` in the BasicFilter constructor, the UserControl's DataContext is set to itself, not to any view model instance. Hence the binding infrastructure searches for the binding source property `LocationFilterLists` in the UserControl, which of course isn't there.

Remove that line from the BasicFilter constructor, and lets the UserControl inherit its DataContext from its parent control (which works automatically). This assumes that the DataContext of e.g. the MainWindow is set somewhere to an instance of MainViewModel.

Comment: I did it using a PropertyChangedCallback, but nothing happens when `LocationFilterLists = nll;` executes. I *am* getting this error message in the output which I don't quite understand: `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'LocationFilterLists' property not found on 'object' ''BasicFilter' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=LocationFilterLists; DataItem='BasicFilter' (Name=''); target element is 'BasicFilter' (Name=''); target property is 'FilterLists' (type 'NamedListList')` I don't need to notify collection changes - once they're set, they won't change.

Comment: Great, this worked! The title didn't show, but that was because of `dockPanel.Children.Clear();` and because I had to set the `DataContext` of `dockPanel` to `this` (`BasicFilter` control). I've added another `DockPanel` named `dockPanelOut` which wraps the existing one and moved the label out of the `dockPanel` and set `dockPanelOut.DataContext = this` and it now works.